# Filter Embedded Array in Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, morphia

I have those classes:

```
@Entity
public class Event implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private ObjectId id;

...

@Embedded
private List<Edition> editions;

...
}
```

and

```
public class Edition implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int number;

...
}
```

I am trying search an Event and filter by an specific edition number.

For instance, if I have an collection such:

```
{
  id : <ObjectID>,
  editions : [
    {number : 1},
    {number : 2}
  ]
}
```

And search by edition 1 the result that I am expecting is:

```
{
  id : <ObjectID>,
  editions : [
    {number : 1}
  ]
}
```

I read about filter in morphia and my query is like this:

```
Query<Event> query = this.basicDAO.createQuery();
query = query.filter("editions.number", <edition number>);

return this.basicDAO.find(query).asList();
```

However I still get the two editions elements. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you'll always get the full document. You can [ignore specific fields](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#ignoring-fields) (whitelisting and blacklisting supported) with `.retrievedFields(false, "foo")`.

You might be able to use the [projection operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) to retrieve the value you are looking for. Try something like this:

```
query.filter("editions.number", <edition number>).retrievedFields(true, "editions.$");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @xeraa, I was using retrievedFields in other queries however I did not realise that in this case filter must used retrievedFields